# Taking user input in C++ without c++ standard library classes

Tags: c++

I'm trying to take user input from the console without using the c++ standard library classes. Here's my code

```
while(true){
        std::string line = " ";

        while (getline(std::cin, line)) {

            std::string arr[100];
            int i = 0, len = 0;
            for (int j=0; j < line.length(); j++) {
                if(line[j] ==' ' || line[j] == '\n'){
                    std::string word = line.substr(i, j);
                    arr[len] = word;
                    len++;
                    i = j;
                }
            }
            for (int k = 0; k <len ; ++k) {
                std::cout<<arr[k]<<std::endl;
            }

        }

        //break;
    }
```

The idea is to identify each word and store it in an array. However this program only identifies the first word. Any idea, what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: How do you feel about stringstream?

Comment: If you do not want to use STL, why not use plain C code? `scanf` and `printf`. Just include the header `stdio.h` and you should be ready to go...

Comment: If you *can't* use `std::vector`, then you need to make sure you don't go outside of the array. But you *should* use `std::vector`.

Comment: std::string is not STL

Comment: Please read the documentation for `getline` and `substr` (getline does not extract '\n' and substr takes a position and length)

Comment: stringstream is also STL

Comment: What exactly do you mean by STL classes and why?

Comment: @ThomasG I don't recall `stringstream` being in the STL. But I think the problem is that you're talking about the C++ standard library, not the STL.

Comment: @ThomasG The correct term is c++ standard library not STL, that's back from the 90ies. Also, how does `getline(std::cin, line)` not use c++ standard library functions or classes? If you want c code, use c functions like `scanf()`.

Comment: Can one even say STL exists? It was borged into std 17 years ago. Language lawyering aside, better wording would be to disallow the use of the containers library with maybe an additional ban on stringstream.

Comment: What happens if you need more than 100 strings in `arr`? Why use STL so far but then stop here and make your code unsafe?

Answer (score 1):

In reading this, it would seem your problem lies on the line `std::string word = line.substr(i, j);`. You have to understand that `substr`'s arguments are not "from i to j", but "from i, j characters". [Read the documentation.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) :)

I haven't tested this, so it might not be perfect, but the principle is there.

```
while(true){
        std::string line = " ";

        while (getline(std::cin, line)) {

            std::string arr[100];
            int num_chars = 0, word = 0;
            for (int i=0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                /*We increment i, so every non-space character is one we
                 * will include in the word.*/
                num_chars++;
                if(line[i] ==' ' || line[i] == '\n'){
                    /*We want all characters from i to i+num_chars, that is
                     * we want all characters from j, forward i indices.
                     */
                    std::string word = line.substr(i, num_chars);
                    arr[word] = word;
                    word++;
                    //We reset i here, in prep for parsing the next word.
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
            for (int k = 0; k <len ; ++k) {
                std::cout<<arr[k]<<std::endl;
            }

        }

        //break;
    }
```

Two other considerations:

1) Beware the single-letter variables, as it makes it far harder to read your code later. `i` is standard for a loop **i**terator or **i**ndex, with `j` being the next *when you're nesting for loops*. However, `i` is not suitable for the "length of the word". Similarly, `len` is not suitable for the index of the word being stored. I changed the variables in the code to make it easier to read.

2) I would seriously consider revisiting your loop structure. `while` is common and very useful, but it is also highly prone to infinite loops. In fact, `while(true)` IS an infinite loop, so if you don't reach `break` for whatever reason, you'll wind up with some serious issues.

--

I would also agree that, if you want to avoid "STL" (and, actually `std::` and `stl` are commonly confused, but are not the same thing...so let's say you want to avoid `std`), you'll want to avoid `std::string` and `std::cin`. Use C-strings and `scanf`/`printf` instead, as Nidhoegger suggested. It is more efficient than the `std` options, but it also more prone to the errors and "undefined behaviors" characteristic to C. It would take more effort, but would yield a more efficient result if you do it right.

While we're at it, I do NOT recommend `std::stringstream` unless your other tools cannot do the job well. That class has serious performance and efficiency problems, which are well-documented. I only recommend using it in cases where writing your own code with `std::string` and such would be either too laborious or have a high probability of being inefficient. This is NOT one of those cases.

Comment: While I agree with your assessment, it dismisses the case for stringstream. It's brutally easy to use, and one should focus on getting the business logic right, rather than the nitty-gritty of getting data in. Unless the nitty-gritty of getting data in *is* the business logic or the brutal inefficiency of an extremely generalized tool like stringstream gets in the way of performing the business logic within the required parameters. For homework, the business logic isn't the code,  it's learning the lesson the homework's supposed to teach. Get it done, learn, and move on to the next assignment.

Comment: @user4581301: On the one hand, yes, you're right. "Get it done" is a good approach usually. On the other hand, there's an inherent danger in getting habitually comfortable with a solution as inefficient as `std::stringstream`. The internet is rife with flippant recommendations to use it, including many cases where it will have detrimental effects on performance. One should learn how to do things the manual way early, like learning to drive a stick-shift car. If you know how, you'll have no problems driving an automatic. Plus, you can better discern when to use `stringstream`, and when NOT to.

Comment: It is quite likely that the only disagreement we may have on this topic is when to teach manual.

Comment: @user4581301: Probably, which is not a problem at all. And thank you for the civil discussion/debate. The world (and Stackoverflow) needs more people like you! (Also, happy International Day of Peace, ironically enough.)